# User permissions on webserver for different users of group www-data

Tags: permissions, webserver

I have a problem with the permissions on my webserver.

I have two users of the group `www-data`, which log in via ssh key.

So if `user1` generates a new folder or new files, `user2` has no permissions to write into that new folder.
The new folder has the permission `0755`, but should be `0775`.

How can I fix it or is there any other solution for this problem?